# php FTP file: How can check if a file is open by another process

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp, video-streaming

I have a list of videos (.mp4) in a remote server.
From my application codeigniter, I connect with FTP to the remote server and I can list those videos.
I want to rename those files, but I should verify if file is opened by another process (video is playing) before renaming it.
How can check if a file is opened by another process with php?

This my code:

```
$ftp = new Simple_ftp();
$ftp->init("server",'login','password');
$conn_id = $ftp->connexion();
if($conn_id == 3){
    $files = $ftp->ls('path_files');
    foreach($files as $file){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: by using ftp you have no chance ... only the os of the remote server maybe can figure out if a file is in use ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check for that having only FTP access.

If the server is using Linux based OS and you have ssh access, you can remotely connect and use the `lsof` program.

Comment: I known the reading link of the video (http://exemple.com/video.mp4), I dont have chance to known it is  opened or not?

Comment: Having FTP only access there is no way to know if it is currently opened or not. The protocol don't have such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of knowing by FTP, however other methods I suggest taking a look at the following: [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

It checks for file locking